# Customize Devise sign_in to accommodate two flows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Rails 4.0 and Devise 3.3.0

I have two sign_in flows I'd like to provide. One that is the usual sign_in and another that transfers a bunch of photos a guest_user uploaded to the current_user's account.  I have the functionality working for each of these so that isn't a problem.

For the guest -> signed_in flow, I basically want to sign the user in and then transfer the content.
It looks like:

```
def sign_in_and_save (resource_or_scope, *args)        
  super 
  move_content guest_user, current_user
end
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to tell Devise to use this method for this scenario instead of the usual sign_in flow.  I could modify the current sign_in method, but I would still have to pass a parameter in the form (I'm assuming) to tell the method there is a special case.

The views are the same. In scenario 1 I display: Sign In and scenario 2 I display: Sign In and Save in the navigation.

Is there a preference and why and how would I go about it?